# @media Not Working on All Devices

Tags: html, css

I've recently deployed a website [infortion.com](https://www.infortion.com/). Everything seems working fine, accept some users have reported that website is not viewing properly on their mobile devices! Also, they sent me screenshots which clearly shows that `@media` tags are not working on their phone.

I tried opening it from several browsers on my mobile (gionee P5W - android 6 ) & it's working fine, but not for them.

Here's the meta tag,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Here's the structure of CSS file for small devices,

```
@media all and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:480px){
# CSS
} 

@media all and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:320px){
 # CSS
}
```

How can we fix this problem? Thank You . . .

Comment: Have you confirmed it's not a caching issue? Are these users who may have viewed your website prior to you adding your mobile CSS? You can confirm this by adding somethling like `?v=1.0` to the end of your CSS href in your `<link>`

Comment: @dukedevil294 I've changed the entire CSS file name everywhere. Still not fixed.

Comment: `@media (max-width: 480px) {...}` &
`@media (max-width: 320px) {...}`
is all you really need.

Answer (score -1):

Try using your media-query like so:

```
@media screen (max-width: 320px){
 # CSS
}
```

It will target any screen (and any device) with a `max-width` of `320px`. Because the `max-width` is set, it means that anything else under `320px` is also targeted, so adding a `min-width` would be redundant.

The meta tag is correct and should not cause any issues.

Let me know how that works out, and if any problems remain, provide some screenshots.

Comment: Sir, will it work for multiple media queries as well? I've other queries too for big screen sizes.

Comment: Yes, of course. You're next media-query would be, for example: `@media screen (max-width: 768px)` to target tablet sizes. Because there is already another media-query for 320px and lower, the next one will over target the `max-width` of 320px+ to 768px. Let me know if you have any future problems.

Comment: Sir, I've just rechecked everything, It's still not working for devices below 320px.

Comment: Sir, `@media only screen and (max-width: 320px)` worked fine :) Thank You for help!